# Java Int Confusion

Tags: java, int

I understand that, in Java, there are no unsigned numbers, they're all signed with wizardry behind the scenes to make sense of it.

So, I am puzzled by this, and it's probably that wizardry that I mentioned before that's eluding me.

```
private static int broadcast = 0xffffffff; //4294967295
```

I'm using IntelliJ for an IDE, and in that, the above statement works fine.  If I replace the hex number with the decimal #, I get a complaint that the number is too large.  It's the same number, what am I missing?

How I'm using it all:

```
package com.company;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

    private final static int broadcast = 0xffffffff;    //4294967295, or 255.255.255.255
    private final static int firstClassE = 0xf0000000;  //4026531840, or 240.0.0.0

    public static int GetIntInetAddress(InetAddress toConvert)
    {
        final byte[] addr = toConvert.getAddress();

        final int ipAddr =
                ((addr[0] & 0xFF) << (3 * 8)) +
                        ((addr[1] & 0xFF) << (2 * 8)) +
                        ((addr[2] & 0xFF) << (1 * 8)) +
                        (addr[3] & 0xFF);

        return ipAddr;
    }

    public static Boolean IsClassEAddress(InetAddress address)
    {
        int curAddr = GetIntInetAddress(address);
        System.out.println(String.format("curAddr: %d, firstClassE: %d, broadcast: %d", curAddr, firstClassE, broadcast));
        return (curAddr >= firstClassE && curAddr < broadcast) ? true : false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        String ip = "10.20.30.40";
        InetAddress someIP = InetAddress.getByName(ip);

        if (IsClassEAddress(someIP))
        {
            // Raise a flag
            System.out.println("Class E IP address detected.");
        }

        // Output of program is:
        // curAddr: 169090600, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1
    }
}
```

In IntelliJ, there's another strange example of this behaviour.  When I examine an address, the inspector is showing both the proper value and the negative value, as I've highlighted with red arrows in the pic below.  Using Windows calc, I put in -84 and converted to hex and received FFF...FAC. When I put in 172, I received just AC... why do I get the same hex number, just preceeded by a 1 in the most sig position?

[image: Another strange example I've seen]

Comment: Are you sure those return the same number? I've seen somewhere that that hex number is actually -1.

Comment: @jhobbie it is -1, it is also 4294967295, because -1 and 4294967295 are also the same number

Comment: Have you every printed this number? You are basically just setting bits here. It should print -1. -1 (using the two's complement) has the same bit pattern as 4294967295.

Comment: The wizardry is explained here: [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is specified in [JLS section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), which has different rules for decimal literals and literals of other bases:

> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than `2147483648` (2<sup>31</sup>), or if the decimal literal `2147483648` appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4).

vs

> The following hexadecimal, octal, and binary literals represent the decimal value -1:
>   `0xffff_ffff`,
>   `0377_7777_7777`, and
>   `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111`
>   It is a compile-time error if a hexadecimal, octal, or binary int literal does not fit in 32 bits.

So that's why the compiler is behaving that way - it's basically as per the spec.

As for why the specification was *written* that way... I suspect it's because constants written in non-decimal bases are usually there for bitmasking techniques and the like - where really you just care about the bits in the value rather than the sign and magnitude of the integer it represents.

Comment: So how do comparisons work then - something else wizardly going on?  Suppose I had the following code:

`private static int broadcast = 0xffffffff;
private final static int firstClassE = 0xf0000000;
...
int curAddr = GetIntInetAddress(address);
return (curAddr >= firstClassE && curAddr < broadcast) ? true : false;`

Is the jvm converting these negative numbers back to positive for the comparisons to work properly?

Comment: @Jon: Separate comparisons from assignments. It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing in that code, given that it's calling an unconventionally-named method we don't know the behaviour of. But no, these are just signed `int` values. The generated code is *identical* to how it would look if you'd written `private static int broadcast = -1; ...`

Comment: Cont'd.  My confusion stems from the fact that a) when I key in FFFFFFFF into my windows calculator and convert to decimal, I get 4294967295 as the equivalent, not -1 and b) if I did get -1 for FFFFFFFF, how does my comparison of some arbitrary IP work - how is the int equivalent of 1.1.1.1 (12544, correct?) < -1?

Comment: @Jon: Well yes, FFFFFFFF would normally be 4294967295 - but when converted to a 32-bit bit pattern and then interpreted as a 2s complement signed integer, you get -1. For the comparison part, you still seem to have some information we're missing - I suggest you post a short but complete program (in the question) - and before you do the comparison, just print out the integers. I suspect that will move your confusion to the implementation of `GetIntInetAddress`. (As an aside, you should change your names to match Java naming conventions...)

Comment: Code posted.  So, I haven't printed out the ints (battling another problem and trying to work through this as a thought exercise ATM).  So, if I have an address (say, 1.2.3.4), it will be larger than the negative number posed by firstClassE  and larger than broadcast ... but in real life, it may be smaller than both, or at the very least (worst case, for me), it will always at least be smaller than broadcast. I was expecting, when I wrote the code, that the largest int I'd see would be broadcast and the range I'd be checking would be between firstClassE and broadcast.

Comment: @Jon: Well you've posted code, but not a short but complete program. (I should be able to copy, paste, compile, run.) *Please* just print out the values. I'm sure that will help you understand the comparison - and then I suspect you should ask a new question about your other method.

Comment: Alright, alright. :) Code updated to a full working program. Output is: `curAddr: 169090600, firstClassE: -268435456, broadcast: -1`  So, I have curAddr > broadcast > firstClassE, which makes no sense, since 10.20.30.40 < 240.0.0.0 < 255.255.255.255. So confused.

Comment: @Jon: Well that sounds like it's just a two's-complement issue, effectively, no?

Comment: Well... I dunno.  I've not a great understanding of the 2's complement thingy (the wiki page was kinda heavy... any "Two's Complement for Dummies" pages out there?)  So how, or why, would java put some numbers as negative and others as positive?  And how does it know that those numbers it made negative are really positive and bigger than my other positive number?  This would be the wizardry I mentioned in my OP.  :)

Comment: I guess I had always understood, incorrectly it might seem now, that the computer represented negative numbers using the same bit pattern as positive, with a 1 in the leftmost position to indicate negative-ness.

Comment: @Jon: The wikipedia page seems fairly clear to me... I don't have any better resources, I'm afraid. Note that this isn't really a Java-specific thing - it's more that it's the native integer representation on pretty much all platforms these days. I'm still not sure what you mean by "how does it know that those numbers it made negative are really positive and bigger than my other positive number" - it doesn't. As you said, `curAddr` (positive) is greater than `broadcast` (-1) is greater than `firstClassE` (big negative). That's just normal maths.

Comment: But, the numbers are not negatives... they are positives being shown as negatives. How can my IP (10.20.30.40) be larger than firstClassE?  It's a smaller int, yet it's positive and my two big IP numbers are shown as negative, smaller than the smaller IP.

Comment: @Jon: No, they're negative numbers. Your translation code is producing negative numbers, which it *must* do given that you've got a range of 2^32 possible addresses to represent, but there are only 2^31 non-negative `int` values. This is now a *long* way from the original topic of the question, which was about numeric *literal* values. Once more, I suggest you ask a new question about why your IP address translation code is returning negative numbers, after thinking about it for a while longer. (Simplify it: imagine the address only had one part. Now remember that `byte` is -128 to 127.)

Comment: @Jon: (And I'm now done on this question. I won't be responding to any more comments. I'll be happy to answer a new question though.)

Answer (score 5):

`0xffffffff` is -1 as an int (although 4294967295 if it was unsigned).

Depending on how you are using the value it probably doesn't matter.  For example, writing the value out to a binary file or using it as a bitmask will write out the same bytes.

If in java, you need to actually use the value 4294967295 as a positive number, you need to use a long.

```
private static long broadcast = 4294967295L;
```

Note the trailing "L" to mark it as a long.